# Change all index values of pandas dataframe to a range

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, for which I set the index to be one of the columns (`frame_number`), as such:

```
              pedestrian_ID      pos_x     pos_y       v_x       v_y
frame_number                                                        
780.0                   1.0   8.456844  3.588066  1.671714  0.176292
786.0                   1.0   9.125530  3.658583  1.662877  0.326723
792.0                   1.0   9.787146  3.849445  1.683334  0.371084
798.0                   1.0  10.472197  3.955450  1.598568  0.264795
804.0                   1.0  11.066000  4.061280  1.574526  0.456390
...                     ...        ...       ...       ...       ...
12381.0                 357.0  10.449366  6.229233  0.596406  0.066591
12381.0                 367.0  11.201661  8.443910  0.000000  0.000000
```

Now I want to change the values of the index to the range `(0, df['frame_number'].unique())` (0 to the number of unique values for the index, `'frame_number'`) as such:

```
              pedestrian_ID      pos_x     pos_y       v_x       v_y
frame_number                                                        
0                   1.0   8.456844  3.588066  1.671714  0.176292
1                   1.0   9.125530  3.658583  1.662877  0.326723
2                   1.0   9.787146  3.849445  1.683334  0.371084
3                   1.0  10.472197  3.955450  1.598568  0.264795
4                   1.0  11.066000  4.061280  1.574526  0.456390
...                     ...        ...       ...       ...       ...
1447                357.0  10.449366  6.229233  0.596406  0.066591
1448                367.0  11.201661  8.443910  0.000000  0.000000
```

For the above specific example, because I know the lowest value for `frame_number` is 780 and that each successive `frame_number` goes up by 6, I can do this:

```
df.index = (df.index - 780).astype(int) // 6
```

To do this more generally (for where my indexed column does not obey such a pattern), I can do:

```
d = {frame: i for i, frame in enumerate(df['frame_number'].unique())}
df.index = np.array([d[frame] for frame in df.index])
```

**Is there a better way to do this, preferably within pandas?**

Just to be extra clear, I don't want to absorb the index back into the dataframe as `df.reset_index()` would, rather I want to preserve the index but change its values to a range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your index to a pandas [Categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) and then substitute your index by the categorical's codes:

```py
df.index = pd.Categorical(df.index).codes
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution is a neat trick.